# Define Laravel 5 route inside subfolder and display it via controller

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have Laravel 5.2.45 app.
I have controller structure like this:

```
App
    Http
        Controllers
            Admin
                AdminController.php
```

inside AdminController.php I have

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;

class AdminController extends Controller 
{

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct() 
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
    $this->middleware('is.admin');
}

public function index()
{
    return view('admin.home');
}

}
```

I have views folder structure like this:

```
views
    admin
        home.blade.php
```

And inside my routes.php I have

```
Route::get('/admin/home', 'Admin\AdminController@index');
```

So I'm trying to get that when I type .../admin/home browser displays home.blade.php inside admin folder.

My routes.php:

```
Route::auth();

Route::get('/', 'FrontController@index');

Route::get('/home', 'FrontController@index');

Route::get('/add_user', 'FrontController@user');

Route::group(['prefix', 'admin', 'namespace' => 'Admin'], function() {
    Route::get('home', 'AdminController@index');
});
```

Comment: drop the leading forward slash so it becomes: `Route::get('admin/home', 'Admin\AdminController@index');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prefix is missing in your **route definition**. Correct it to look like this:

```
<?php
   Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'Admin'], function() {
       Route::get('/home', 'AdminController@index');
   });
```

> Now, try base_url/admin/home in your browser and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use route groups with the namespace and prefix options.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'Admin'], function() {
    Route::get('home', 'AdminController@index');
});
```

Here, the `prefix` allows you to specify the beginning of a URL that should always be in the routes inside the group. So any routes you put inside that group should start with `admin`.

The namespace lets you specifiy a folder/namespace for the controllers you reference. So all the controllers must be in the `App\Http\Controllers\Admin` namespace and the `app/Http/Controllers/Admin` folder.

Comment: I just did that and I get NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
I typed into browser
http://localhost:8888/project/public/admin/home
Controllers and view are in correct folder as I mentioned in question
I tried with return view admin.home, admin/home, home but nothing works

Comment: Can you post the contents of your routes file?

Comment: We both missed error - 'prefix' => 'admin' instead 'prefix', 'admin'
But thanks for great suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You need to drop the leading forward slash so it becomes:

`Route::get('admin/home', 'Admin\AdminController@index');`

Comment: This won't fix the issue, Laravel trims off any extra leading slashes when it registers the routes.

Comment: Yes, this isn't working. Same problem as before. I tried every combination already. /admin/home, /home, home, admin/home, admin.home...